# Client Version Error after installing Azure 1.8

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, azure

I recently installed the Azure SDK 1.8 on my machine but am still using a project that is running version 1.7.1 (June 2012 SP1 for VS2012). Since I did this, every time I try to run my project I get the following error:

```
 ErrorCode<ERRCA0019>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Check the client version. It should be within the allowed version range on the server. If necessary, upgrade the client to the allowed version.

[DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0019>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Check the client version. It should be within the allowed version range on the server. If necessary, upgrade the client to the allowed version.]
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ErrStatus errStatus, Guid trackingId, Exception responseException, Byte[][] payload, EndpointID destination) +767
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ResponseBody respBody, EndpointID destination) +149
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.EstablishConnection(IEnumerable`1 servers, RequestBody request, Func`3 sendMessageDelegate, DataCacheReadyRetryPolicy retryPolicy) +967
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.WcfClientProtocol.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 servers) +606
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName, CreateNewCacheDelegate cacheCreationDelegate, DataCacheInitializationViaCopyDelegate initializeDelegate) +1103
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName) +131
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheFactoryWrapper.CreateDataCacheFromFactory(DataCacheFactory factory, String cacheName) +63
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.CacheHelpers.RunCacheCreationHooks(CacheConnectingEventArgs fetchingEventArgs, IDataCacheFactory dataCacheFactory, Object sender, EventHandler`1 fetchingHandler, EventHandler`1 fetchedHandler) +356
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.CreateInternalProvider(IHttpRuntime httpRuntime, SessionInitializationData initData, IDataCacheFactory dataCacheFactory, EventHandler`1 cacheFetching, EventHandler`1 cacheFetched) +447
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.GetInternalProvider() +315
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.ResetItemTimeout(HttpContext context, String id) +59
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +707
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12600474
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

I have not had much luck finding a solution. Some forums have mentioned using a different AppFabric version, but they all seem to be referring to running it in the actual Azure cloud service and I can't even get it to run on my local machine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem while upgrading to the October 2012 release. I resolved it by removing all the caching references in my project, and then installing the [Windows Azure Shared Caching package from NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Caching/).

I'm not sure if the resulting project will still run with the June 2012 SDK. But it's worth a try.